# C# Properties - Set question

Tags: c#

I'm working in C# and I'm starting to play with properties. One thing I don't know is what is the best way/where to put the logic for the set accessors of class properties and how to handle the errors.

For instance, say I have this (basic) class:

```
class Person
{
    private int _Age = 18;

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _Age;
        }
        set
        {
            _Age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now say I have a requirement on the Age property, 0 < Age < 100. Where do I put the logic for this?

Should I put it in the property?

```
public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _Age;
        }
        set
        {
           if (value < 0 || value > 99)
               // handle error
           else
               _Age = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
```

or through class that is creating a Person object?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Person him = new Person();
   int NewAge = -10;

   if (NewAge < 0 || NewAge > 100)
      // handle error 
   else
      him.Age = NewAge;
}
```

Now what if there is a problem with the NewAge (it doesn't meet my constraint)? Should I create a custom exception and throw that? Should I just print a message saying supply a valid age?

I've done some Googling and I cannot find anything that fully answers my questions. I need a book :-/

Comment: Note also that your setter does not need `Convert.ToInt32(value)`... because the property is an `int`, the `value` will also be an `int`.

Comment: Isn't this considered defensive programming? Or am I taking it to far?

Comment: You're taking it too far. There is no possibility that the thing you get is not an int.

Comment: Look at it this way: before you call "convert" you are already comparing "value" to integers to determine its range. If the value wasn't necessarily an int, then you would have to be converting it BEFORE the comparison, right?

Comment: Also, while we're at it, "Age" is probably the wrong thing to store in a Person. "Age" constantly changes, "Birthday" never changes. Store the person's date of birth and then you can easily calculate their age when you need to.

Comment: You're absolutely right about storing the age vs the birth date. I was using age for simplicity and learning what to do vs what not to do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the property setter, it is there for that reason (adding functionality to a field).

If out of range value is passed in, you can throw [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) or just set it to minimum (or maximum) value, but this depends on your process requirement.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException and not just Exception

Comment: I would add a little nuance to this in saying that the property setter is generally the appropriate place,... but ONLY for things you are absolutely certain must be true at all times. Checks that may have exceptions (pardon the pun) should probably go into a validation method instead, so that the user of the class can determine whether erroring out is appropriate. The main reason for saying this is that it is not unreasonable in the general case to allow ages over 99 or a 100 (which the original question does not allow for some reason)

Comment: I would:
1) clearly document the behaviour and requirement of this property (so user knows how to use it) and
2) put a clear message on the exception thrown
3) this will create a clean code (not littered with validation methods that will confuse future developers)

Answer (score 11):

I'd implement it like this:

```
public int Age
{
    get
    {
        return _Age;
    }
    set
    {
       if (IsValidAge(value))
           _Age = value;
       else
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", string.Format("value should be between {0} and {1} inclusive.", MinAge, MaxAge));
    }
}

private bool IsValidAge(int age)
{
    return (age >= MinAge && age <= MaxAge);
}
```

A few things to note:

- Don't change their value instead of throwing an exception, this is unexpected behaviour.
- The .NET framework throws Argument* exceptions in setters, so I'd say it's a good idea to follow this practice. In this case ArgumentOutOfRangeException is perfect, IMO.
- When referring to the argument in exception messages and xml docs, the standard is to call the argument "value", not the name of your property.
- I'd recommend MinAge and MaxAge as private consts in your class, don't fall into the trap of hardcoding error messages with range boundaries in them, there's nothing worse than being told "5 in invalid, please enter a number between 1 and 10" when someone changes the spec later on but forgets to update a string.

Comment: I Agree with an implementation like this. You should definitely do the validation on set and it should be an external call. I'd also recommend moving it out to somewhere more accessible if it's something that you might want to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

You will want to put the logic in the setter and throw an exception if it doesn't meet the requirement. However, you will also want to create an IsValidAge static method or something so that classes creating a Person can check the age value instead of just seeing if it throws an exception. Alternatively you could have MinAge and MaxAge properties so calling code could check if the age they're about to set is between it.

Don't create a custom exception type though, use ArgumentOutOfRangeException or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Put it in the property. That's one of the main purposes of properties!

Consider that you'll be placing the responsibility in the lowest level possible. The example you gave doesn't require anything other than the *value* parameter in order to make its decision. It doesn't even depend on other members of the same class. There's no reason for the rest of the class to know how validity works for the Age property, and certainly no reason for any other piece of code to know it.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into the IDataErrorInfo interface.

By implementing this interface in your class, you'll open the class to other mechanisms that can benefit from the additional error information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to play devil's advocate and give an answer why you WOULD NOT want to put it in the setter.  There are plenty of cases when you want to be able to set the value of your Age property, and at a later time ask if that object is valid in a holistic sense.

For instance, keep your property simple:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Then when an invalid value is passed in you can have some IsValid function which indicates if the object in question is ok.  This can be extremely useful because you can do more complicated validation other than a simple Age restriction.

```
bool IsValid()
{
   if (Age < 0 || Age > 99)
     return false;
}
```

For something simple like this there isn't a lot of benefit, but consider also that you can use this in your persistence layer so you can ensure that any object that is NOT valid will never be persisted.  In those cases you don't necessarily want to throw an exception.

Also consider this:

```
DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
DateTime EndDate { get; set;}

bool IsValid()
{
   return StartDate > EndDate      
}
```

This is only pseudocode, but you get my point.  This is something you can't do inside a setter, or at least, not in a way that is maintainable.

Comment: This is an interesting point of view. While I agree that having a separate IsValid function might be useful, I don't understand why I'm allowed to create a condition where the model itself can be invalid. Would catching an error as early as possible reduces headaches in the future? What happens when the persistence code forgot to call IsValid? That is a one big thing to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setter, and use ArgumentOutOfRangeException, as others have already said.

Sometimes you will call another method, usually something like OnAgeChanged(int age), where you could perform the validation (which may be a call to yet another method so you can use it anywhere) and invoke an event handler, which if hooked up, may have other logic to apply depending on how you are using your object.  That may not be necessary in your scenario, but it's pretty common to do that for properties.  Especially if you are going to update a form - the form would hook into the AgeChanged event to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing factored design (ie. it is important that the state of the object be valid at all points during the life of the object), then you might want to set and check this in the constructor.  In a component design, you'd want to check this in the method that uses the property, e.g.

```
class Person
{
  public int calculateTimeToExpiration()
  {
  if (Age < 0 || Age > 100)
     //throw
  }
}
```

Static void main is client code and not a good place for business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! In case you were curious here is what I change my little example (although it is more detailed now) to (based from the comments).

```
class Person
{
    private string _FirstName = "Joe";
    private string _LastName = "Smith";
    private int _Age = 18;

    private const int MinAge = 1;
    private const int MaxAge = 99;

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(string FirstName, string LastName, int Age)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _LastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _LastName = value;
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _Age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (IsValidAge(value))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value","Please enter a positive age less than 100.");
            else
                _Age = value;
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidAge(int age)
    {
        return (age < MinAge || age > MaxAge);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Age == 1) 
            return "My name is " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " and I am " + Age + " year old.";
        else
            return "My name is " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " and I am " + Age + " years old.";
    }  
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person him, her;

        try
        {
            him = new Person("Joe Bob", "McGruff", 1);
            Console.WriteLine(him);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException range)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(range.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            her = new Person();
            her.Age = -5;
            Console.WriteLine(her);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException range)
        {
            Console.Write(range.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I would change the logic in your IsValidAge method. You're calling the method "IsValid" yet, you're returning true for invalid. Also, no need to Convert.ToInt in your setter. The value will automatically be an int. Remember, properties are just syntactic sugar for methods. Under the hood it's tunred into a private void set_Age(int x){..} where x -> value. Therefore, there's NO WAY for value NOT to be an int.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated answer is good but you should clean up one little piece in your setter/validation

```
 public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _Age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!IsValidAge(value))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Age","Please enter a positive age less than 100.");

             _Age = value;
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidAge(int age)
    {
        return (age > MinAge && age < MaxAge);
    }
```